# Syncronize 2 digital signals

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, timing, synchronization

I have 2 digital signals, and I want them to synchronize.

[image]

the lower frequency yellow signal takes 32 clock cycles.
the higher frequency blue signal takes 8 clock cycles.

I need the lower frequency yellow signal's falling edge to syncronize with the higher frequency signal's rising edge something like this
[image]

my circuit is

[image]

the high frequency signal comes from the 74hc93 while the low frequency signal comes from a microcontroller, and the clock(SCLK) connected to the 74hc93 is connected to the microcontroller.

Comment: Yellowsub, Do you have access to the higher-frequency clock? Looks like you do. (*SCLK*) But I want to be sure.

Comment: yes, the Sclock has a higher frequency than both

Answer (score 2):

Because you want a power of 2 integer division ratio, something like a frequency divider would be the simplest way. A few D-FF's would implement this.

If you want to keep the microcontroller as the signal source, you could count the time between rising edges, and use that as a period. Then use the microcontroller's timer to toggle a signal every 'x' periods.